# Get this embedded video to play in IE

Tags: html, flash, video

I have an unusual request. A client wants to play a video from the un.org webcast page. My friend had copied the rendered  directly and posted it onto a page. Which to my surprise worked, however it does not work in IE only. Any suggestions or advice (Other then the clearly poor choice in implementing this task would be greatly appreciated)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/Db01RL1M (All alone it works on firefox, safari and Chrome.)

Comment: Well I was not really excited about either answer, but I guess yours win due to the fact that I asked for suggestions. You win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of the native Flash viewer.  So, if it was me, I would embed Flowplayer into my site, due to the huge advantages and extra features it offers over the standard browser.  Then, feed Flow the video from the URL you've provided in your code. (http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf)

My guess is that this will take care of the problem straightaway.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "movie" param.

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf">
```

Final code:

```
<object width="640" height="360" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="main_player" name="media" class="video" data="http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf">
<param name="play" value="false">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="scale" value="noborder">
<param name="bgcolor" value="000000">
<param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain">
<param name="flashvars" value="file=specialevents/2010/se100923pm1.flv&amp;image=http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.jpg&amp;autostart=false&amp;dock=true&amp;streamer=rtmp://cp8784.edgefcs.net/ondemand&amp;plugins=http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/sharing.swf, http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/captions-1.swf&amp;captions.file=http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.srt&amp;sharing.link=2010/09/heads-of-state-and-government-luncheon-toast-at-the-beginning&amp;sharing.code=%3Cobject%20width%3D%22480%22%20height%3D%22270%22%3E%3Cparam%20name%3D%22movie%22%20value%3D%22http%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf%22%20/%3E%3Cparam%20name%3D%22allowFullScreen%22%20value%3D%22true%22%20/%3E%3Cparam%20name%3D%22bgcolor%22%20value%3D%22000000%22%20/%3E%3Cparam%20name%3D%22allowscriptaccess%22%20value%3D%22always%22%3E%3C/param%3E%3Cparam%20name%3D%22flashvars%22%20value%3D%22file%3Dspecialevents/2010/se100923pm1.flv%26image%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.jpg%26autostart%3Dfalse%26controlbar%3Dover%26dock%3Dtrue%26plugins%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/captions-1.swf%26captions.file%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.srt%26stretching%3Duniform%26streamer%3Drtmp%3A//cp8784.edgefcs.net/ondemand%22%20/%3E%3Cembed%20src%3D%22http%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/player.swf%3Ffile%3Dspecialevents/2010/se100923pm1.flv%26image%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.jpg%26autostart%3Dfalse%26%26controlbar%3Dover%26dock%3Dtrue%26plugins%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/captions-1.swf%26captions.file%3Dhttp%3A//www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/2010/09/full/se100923pm1.srt%26stretching%3Duniform%26streamer%3Drtmp%3A//cp8784.edgefcs.net/ondemand%22%20width%3D%22480%22%20height%3D%22270%22%20type%3D%22application/x-shockwave-flash%22%20allowfullscreen%3D%22true%22%20allowscriptaccess%3D%22always%22/%3E%3C/object%3E&amp;stretching=uniform&amp;controlbar=over&amp;skin=http://www.unmultimedia.org/tv/webcast/swfs/webcast-skin.swf"></object>
```